# If XML Doesn't exist, Create one in order to append it. (C# , ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if my file does exist first, but if not.. How can i make it exist?

```
 if (File.Exists(Filepath))
 {

     // if it does exist, itll show datas as data grid view

     dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

 }

 else
 {


     // if it doesnt exist, how can i make it exist? or create an XML file

 }
```

Comment: Just create a new file programmatically.

Comment: @progrAmmar how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `XmlDocument` and `XmlTextWriter`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<sample></sample>");  //your content here
// Save the document to a file
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("sample.xml", null);
doc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: Its done, thank you, I got errors at doc.loadxml, but i managed to debugged it, thanks for giving me a better flow. Kudos

Comment: PS: To everyone that will do this, put this at the bottom of doc.Save(writer)      



----> writer.Close();

Comment: @Chddz - better advise will be wrap `XmlTextWriter` with `using`

Answer (score 0):

Use StreamWriter to create a new file, specify the **path**.

You can do this:

```
  using(var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
  {
      tw.WriteLine("New file content");
  }
```

Comment: no need to Close() because of the 'using', or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right D le, its automatically closed and flushed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a `FileStream` with the `File` class.

```
if (!File.Exists(Filepath))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(Filepath))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Text in the file.");
        // Add some information to the file.
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by using LINQ to XML types without explicit using of writers

```
if (File.Exists(Filepath))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    var document =  
        new XDocument(new XElement("root", 
                                   new XElement("one", "value 1"),
                                   new XElement("two", "value 2"));

    document.Save(FilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Xml.Linq; 

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                         new XElement("YourNodeName")
                        );
doc.Save("your_doc_name.xml");
```