# How to create file with a written data inside C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 var myFile = File.Create("sample.xml");

//insert root element here
//or something like this                           
//<?xml version="1.0"?>
//< Information xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" //xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>


myFile.Close();
```

cause, if the system cant locate the "sample.xml" it will create a new sample.xml..
But its empty. I want it to create a new sample.xml with root element inside, how can i do it?

Comment: There are several ways but to stay simple, see if the file exists already or not, if not run a method that creates and writes the root element you want to it.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII thats what i want to do, but i dont know how

Comment: What part?  Do you not know how to make XML files or not know how to write to files in general?  I can mock it up and hope it's an answer but let me know what part you're lost with.

Comment: Well, you could write some code that actually writes to the file. Or, better yet, you could search this site for existing questions about how to write to XML from C# (there are dozens of them).

Comment: Im having problem, whenever  my system try to load the 'sample.xml' it just created using "File.Create("sample.xml");". Because it cant find the root element. Because sample.xml is empty.

Comment: I'm confused, you've asked almost the identical question before and accepted an answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822130/if-xml-doesnt-exist-create-one-in-order-to-append-it-c-asp-net. What is different now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML file would be something like this-

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Now you can similarly take this content and write to a file.

```
string xmlContent = @"<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>";

string path = @"C:\Souvik\Test.xml";

File.WriteAllText(path, xmlContent);
```

The `File.WriteAllText` will create a new file or overwrite an existing file.

Comment: How often do we write XML to a file from a hand crafted string? Almost never.

Comment: @mason Rarely. This is just for illustration. The XML contents should be dynamically created and templated through the code IMO.